# How do I set up a Web Proxy that I can use to test functionality related to Http Requests?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webrequest

one of the users of my applications must connect to a web proxy before he can connect to our website. he tells me that he keeps getting 401 errors even when he specifies the proxy's ip, port, username & password. I have no way to test this functionality because I don't need to use a proxy to connect to our website. For all I know the problem relates to the way I am making the HttpRequest, but again, I have no way to test this functionality.

How can I set up a web proxy that will allow me to test this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of you are on Windows, go grab CC Proxy http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/ and install it. It's free and and can be configured to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the [`Proxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) property on the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

For example here's how you could specify a proxy server using default network credentials:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.mydomain.com", 8080);
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: I think I am doing that already, but since I don't need to use a proxy to connect to the website, there is no way for me to know if I am setting up that property correctly. I'd like to set up a scenario where I must use a proxy in order to connect to the website. That way I will see with my own eyes whether the HttpRequests works with proxies or not.

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement. If you want your HTTP requests to go through a proxy server you should set the `Proxy` property. If you just want to see the HTTP data being exchanged without any proxy you could simply enable tracing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

Comment: I understand that part. The application works 2 ways: with proxies and without proxies. I have confirmed that it works fine when no proxies are required. I have not confirmed that it works fine when proxies are required. I only have the user's testimonial that it doesn't work. So I want to test to make sure the application works when proxies are required. But I don't know how to test this functionality because I don't have a proxy for which I must provide a username and password before I can connect to the website. I'd like to know how to set up a proxy that I can use for testing purposes.

Comment: Alright, then simply install [`Fiddler`](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and then configure the Proxy property on your request to `http://localhost:8888` which is the default port on which Fiddler opens a proxy server.